# Why is this generating 3913 as the year

Tags: android, date

I wrote some code that I am try to use as a comparison for a subscription so this piece of code was supposed to dump the current date. The month and day are correct but the year is off by about 1900 or so any ideas as to why

```
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
Date validDate = new Date(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    complain(validDate.toString());
```

complain is a function I wrote to simply the dump the value of a string to the screen in an alert box

It shows this 3913-02-10

I need to get this fixed before I start doing comparisons so the quicker the better

OK I added some new code and not using the depracated Date any longer but now my month is of by 1 it shows 2013 1 10

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    complain(String.valueOf(year) + " " + String.valueOf(month) + " " + String.valueOf(day));
```

After further research I found that MONTH returns the correct value but I have to say this is VERY unintuitive I would think  that it would coincide with normal understandings of the date format
This has January set to 0, February to 1, March to 2, etc. it is non intuitive.

Thanks to all

Comment: now that you mention it it sounds like it could be a Y2K thing which is crazy but kinda makes sense

Comment: Your month isn't off by one. Like others have noted, check the Javadoc. Month is zero-indexed, so January=0, February=1, etc... Please accept an answer as correct, since you said your original problem is fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a [deprecated constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) that takes the year - 1900 as its first argument.

Comment: what is the current constructor?                                    Do you mean year + 1900 because that is what is shown 2013 + 1900

Comment: No, because the javadoc says so. It also recommends using the GregorianCalendar constructor instead.

Comment: @JeffJanes assylias included a link to the current Javadoc, please go read it.  Also scroll up to the section "Constructors" where for each deprecated constructor the alternative is offered.  If you're serious about programming in Java being able to work with the extensive Javadocs is really a crucial skill.

Comment: I did look at that document as suggested but after I asked for the contructor

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're gonna end up doing with the app, take this with a grain of salt:

Just subtract 1900 from the year and send that to your method or whatever you're doing.

Note: THIS IS A TERRIBLE PROGRAMMING PRACTICE and if this is anything other than self-education, FIND A BETTER WAY.